# Ignore type declaration until last recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion, types, tuples

I'm trying to write a function which converts data in a tuple into a string for a program that does run length encoding. I've written it previously using append but I've been trying to improve it.

The function decode should take a list of tuples and then return a string.

**Examples**

```
> decode [('h',7),('s',3),('g',1)]
"hhhhhhhsssg"
> decode [('z',9),('z',1)]
"zzzzzzzzzz"
```

I initially wrote it recursively using the append function which works fine but isn't optimal, my current implementation looks this:

```
decode :: [(Char,Int)] -> String
decode [] = []
decode x = concat(replicate (snd (head x)) (fst (head x)) : decode (tail x)
```

This then gives me an error on compile as the `decode (tail x)` part doesn't fit the type declaration I'm not allowed to change. I'm sure it's bad practice but would there be a way to get the program not to conform to the type declaration until it finishes recursing?

```
    * Couldn't match type `Char' with `[Char]'
      Expected type: [[Char]]
        Actual type: String
    * In the second argument of `(:)', namely `decode (tail x)'
      In the first argument of `concat', namely
        `(replicate (snd (head x)) (fst (head x)) : decode (tail x))'
      In the expression:
        concat (replicate (snd (head x)) (fst (head x)) : decode (tail x))
   |
35 | decode x = concat(replicate (snd (head x)) (fst (head x)) : decode (tail x))
   |
```

Comment: No, but why don't you just use `++`?

Comment: What is wrong with this? `let x = [('h',7),('s',3),('g',1)] in concat [replicate n c | (c, n) <- x]`.

Comment: @melpomene Was just looking to see if there was a solution that works better in practice, not completely confident in using folds yet either.

Comment: Why folds? And what is all that `(snd (head x))` stuff? `decode ((c, n) : xs) = replicate n c ++ decode xs` seems much simpler to me.

Comment: Yes: almost always, pattern matching is preferrable over `fst`/`snd` etc., and in particular `head` and `tail` are [evil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function).

Comment: If you *really* want to get esoteric, then `decode = concatMap  (uncurry (flip replicate))`.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help, from what I've red on the haskell wiki I would have assumed that it was always better to find a solution that doesn't involve append.

Comment: What do you mean by "append"?

Comment: @melpomene The `++` operation

Comment: @Ali The problem with `(++)` occurs when you repeatedly append a short string to a longer string. Here, you're doing the opposite: adding a long string to the end of a short string.

Comment: I think your problem might actually be a parenthesis in the wrong place. Try `decode x = concat(replicate (snd (head x)) (fst (head x))) : decode (tail x)` instead of what you have right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is with the `:` cons function. it's type is `a -> [a] -> [a]` which means it puts a *single* element a list at the beginning. In your case you are trying to add a *list* (the replicated elements) to the list, that's why `++` works (it's type is `[a] -> [a] -> [a]`). There is no way to simply "ignore the type" because types are interleaved with how haskell compiles/runs, and that's a good thing, in this case the compiler saved you from a "type mismatch" runtime error in other langs.

if you want to write it with `:`, then you can't use `replicate`, you will need to make an auxiliary recursive function that repeats the char, and on zero decodes the rest of the list:

```hs
decodeA :: [(Char,Int)] -> String
decodeA [] = []
decodeA ((c,n):xs) = rep c n
           where rep ch 0 = decodeA xs
                 rep ch m = ch : (rep ch (m-1))
```

now a *more clear* solution arises from using `++`:

```hs
decodeB :: [(Char,Int)] -> String
decodeB [] = []
decodeB ((c,n):xs) = replicate n c ++ decodeB xs
```

and benchmarking both solutions, the second is not only clearer but also faster:

*benchmark code*

```hs
t1 = [('h',7),('s',3),('g',1)]
t2 = [('z',9),('z',1)]
t3 = [('a',10000), ('b',10000), ('c',10000),('d',10000), ('e',10000), ('f',10000)]

main = defaultMain [
  bgroup "decode" [ bench "t1 decodeA" $ nf decodeA t1
                  , bench "t2 decodeA" $ nf decodeA t2
                  , bench "t3 decodeA" $ nf decodeA t3
                  , bench "t1 decodeB" $ nf decodeB t1
                  , bench "t2 decodeB" $ nf decodeB t2
                  , bench "t3 decodeB" $ nf decodeB t3
                   ]
```

*benchmark results*

```sh
benchmarking decode/t1 decodeA
time                 7.152 μs   (7.093 μs .. 7.225 μs)
                     0.999 R²   (0.998 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 7.129 μs   (7.091 μs .. 7.216 μs)
std dev              190.6 ns   (69.72 ns .. 354.5 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 31% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking decode/t2 decodeA
time                 6.283 μs   (6.235 μs .. 6.340 μs)
                     0.999 R²   (0.999 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 6.268 μs   (6.239 μs .. 6.326 μs)
std dev              137.8 ns   (71.41 ns .. 211.7 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 24% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking decode/t3 decodeA
time                 32.67 ms   (32.31 ms .. 33.08 ms)
                     0.999 R²   (0.998 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 32.68 ms   (32.53 ms .. 32.93 ms)
std dev              406.7 μs   (238.0 μs .. 613.5 μs)

benchmarking decode/t1 decodeB
time                 1.208 μs   (1.199 μs .. 1.220 μs)
                     1.000 R²   (0.999 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 1.212 μs   (1.204 μs .. 1.228 μs)
std dev              34.30 ns   (19.59 ns .. 62.18 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 38% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking decode/t2 decodeB
time                 923.6 ns   (916.9 ns .. 931.6 ns)
                     0.999 R²   (0.997 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 923.8 ns   (917.0 ns .. 950.3 ns)
std dev              38.01 ns   (9.440 ns .. 84.90 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 57% (severely inflated)

benchmarking decode/t3 decodeB
time                 1.250 ms   (1.229 ms .. 1.274 ms)
                     0.997 R²   (0.995 R² .. 0.999 R²)
mean                 1.248 ms   (1.239 ms .. 1.269 ms)
std dev              47.55 μs   (32.05 μs .. 78.69 μs)
variance introduced by outliers: 26% (moderately inflated)
```

in this case, `decodeB` is 32 times faster than `decodeA` on the biggest test case

Comment: What a great first post to StackOverflow. Welcome!

Answer (score 2):

In Haskell we do not suppress errors, we fix them. The minimal edit(s) to fix the problem are:

```
decode :: [(Char,Int)] -> String
decode [] = []
decode x = -- concat(replicate (snd (head x)) (fst (head x)) : decode (tail x))  -- BAD
         =    concat[replicate (snd (head x)) (fst (head x)) , decode (tail x)]   -- OK
         =    concat(replicate (snd (head x)) (fst (head x)) : [decode (tail x)]) -- OK
```

Of course `concat [a,b] == a ++ b`, and thus

```
         =           replicate (snd (head x)) (fst (head x)) ++ decode (tail x)
```

i.e.

```
decode ((c,i):xs) =  replicate i c ++ decode xs
```

Thus, among many other possibilities suggested in the comments,

```
decode :: [(Char,Int)] -> String
decode xs = [ c | (c,i) <- xs, _ <- [1..i]]
```

Comment: Your first line is true for all languages in fact for all of life.